# Bind regular expression from json to typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on angular 7 project. I have config.json file in which one of the label's name is inputmask'

config.json

```
{
"name" : "abc",
"maskRegExp" : "[/[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/]"
```

typescript file

```
export class sampleComponent implements OnInit {

getExp : any;

  ngOnInit(){
     this.getExp = this.data.maskRegExp; //returns as string which shouldn't
}
```

Expected data

```
 this.getExp = [/[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/];
  }
```

The issue is json is not returned by the regular expression instead it's sent as a string. I know for people it might look like a dumb question but i am new to angular/javascript. Please help me with some sample code.

When I console.log this.getExp, I want the output to be as followed image

[image]

But I am receiving like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To convert a string to a regexp you can use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object:

```
this.getExp = new RegExp(this.data.maskRegExp);
```

If you want the output as you said above, you apparently should not use RegExp, but just split the string by comma + space.

```
this.getExp = this.data.maskRegExp.split(', ');
```

If you want it to be an array of regular expressions, you can do the following:

```
this.getExp = this.data.maskRegExp.split(', ').map((r) => new RegExp(r));
```

Comment: please check the updated question. Added additional information

Answer (score 1):

You have a Regexp object in JS :

```js
const str = "[/[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/]";

const regex = new RegExp(str, 'gi');

console.log(regex);
```

They're exactly the same, but with that constructor, you can create a regex from a string.

Comment: please check the updated question. Added additional information

Comment: @rakesh your need isn't clear at all. Please explain what you're trying to do. I've shown you how to create a regex from a string, which was what you wanted at first. Now you want an array of regexes ? Is that it ?

Comment: i want  array of regexes